# error inserting query strings into db php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

> > code updated

i have a table called vote with three fields ans_1,ans_2,ans_3
query strings number is 2 or 3 according to answers the admin is going to save
so they look like this ?1=aaa&2=bbb or ?1=aaa&2=bbb&3=ccc
my point is to save every query string in a column so i use the code below but it keeps using the last value of the query string only

```
$queries = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$answers = explode("&",$queries );
$num = count($answers);
foreach($answers as $val){
$chars= strlen($val);
$test = substr($val,2,$chars-2);
for($x=1; $x<=$num; $x++){
    $Q = "update vote set ans_'$x' = '$test' where Vote_ID = '1'";
    $R = mysql_query($Q);
    if($R) { echo "done"; } else { echo mysql_errno(); }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dynamic columns for which you are substituting `$x`, do not enclose `$x` in quotes:

```
$Q = "update vote set ans_$x = '$test' where Vote_ID = '1'";
```

Please be sure to escape the contents of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
$test = mysql_real_escape_string($test);
```

The proper way to parse a query string in PHP is with [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), rather than attempting to `explode()` on the `&`.

```
$queryvars = array();
$parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queryvars);
foreach ($queryvars as $key=>$value) {
   // do the loop
}
```

However, since you are grabbing the whole query string, and not filtering any specific variables, why not just use `$_GET`?

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
   // do the loop...
   $test = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
   $Q = "update vote set ans_'$x' = '$test' where Vote_ID = '1'";
   $x++;
}
```

#### Update

To help you understand why your code isn't working, I'll modify it here. However, this is not the preferred method of performing this task.  Using `foreach($_GET)` as above is much better. Indenting the loop properly will help reveal the problem:

```
$queries = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$answers = explode("&",$queries );
$num = count($answers);

// Your foreach loops over the available querystring params:
// Start by initializing $x to 0
$x = 0;
foreach($answers as $val){
  $chars= strlen($val);
  $test = substr($val,2,$chars-2);

  // You are already inside the foreach loop, so
  // you don't want to start another loop which uses the same value for $test
  // on each iteration.  Instead $x was set to 0 before the outer foreach...
  // There is no need for an inner loop.
  //for($x=1; $x<=$num; $x++){
    // On first iter here, $x is 0. Increments at the end of the loop iter.
    $Q = "update vote set ans_$x = '$test' where Vote_ID = '1'";
    $R = mysql_query($Q);
    if($R) {
      echo "done"; 
    } else { 
      echo mysql_errno(); 
    }
    // On each iteration, increment $x here.
    $x++;
  //} // the inner for loop, commented out...
}
```

Comment: sure i use mysql_real_escape_string for security but i tried to make it as simple as possible here thanks a lot

Comment: still there's an error it keeps updating all columns with the last query string only

Comment: no the main version after replacing ans_'$x' with ans_$x didn't try GET yet was just checking if the main code is going to work

Comment: @Yasser because in your code you set `$test` outside of the for loop which increments `$x`.  It isn't going to work at all.

Comment: i'm trying to learn and get more experience so if there's any answer with some explanation i'd appreciate it thanks

Comment: ok i got the problem it keeps updtaing the fields wile the foreach loop is still working so it's going to update all fields till the last element in foreach

Comment: thanks a loooooot working now i really appreciate it and the most important is that i understand it now thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the single quotes. Try:

```
$Q = "update vote set ans_$x = '$test' where Vote_ID = '1'";
```

Comment: still there's an error it keeps updating all columns with the last query string only

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around your variable..may want to use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're getting values for the query.

```
$Q = "update vote set `ans_$x` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($test) . "' where Vote_ID = '1'";
```

Comment: sure i use mysql_real_escape_string for security but i tried to make it as simple as possible here thanks a lot

Comment: still there's an error it keeps updating all columns with the last query string only

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to not use SQL/PHP in this method.

However to answer why it is not working, you cannot use a PHP variable to set the column in a query as you currently have it.

You would need to change `$Q = "update vote set ans_'$x' = '$test' where Vote_ID = '1'";` to:

```
$Q = "update vote set ans_$x = '$test' where Vote_ID = '1'";
```

Be sure to sanitize the user input for the type of data you are expecting.

Comment: sure i use mysql_real_escape_string for security but i tried to make it as simple as possible here thanks a lot

Comment: still there's an error it keeps updating all columns with the last query string only

Comment: @Yasser is there an error code, or is the code not doing what you expect?

Comment: not doing what i expect though it's a simple for loop it keeps updating columns with the last value guess i should review it from the beginning